# Why do I get different results changing the default operator when my search terms consist of a single word?

Tags: solr

I've been testing different search queries in Solr 8, and I've found a peculiar case.

Using the Standard (Lucene) Query Parser, I search for the word "text". When I search using OR as the default operator, I get 5000+ results. However, using AND as the default operator (without changing anything else), I get 6 results.

If I repeat the same tests with Dismax as the query parser, the default operator does not seem to matter.

Is there a reason for this disparity, or is this a bug?

Comment: Append `debug=all` to your query and look at the parsed result. It would also be helpful to include the start of the response from Solr (where the actual parameters set would be included). The actual query string could also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't clearly visible in Solr Admin, but it turns out that there was some extra text in the query string, which I had copy-pasted from a debug session of our application (that queries Solr).

In short, nothing to see here, mea culpa.